# 'x' must be numeric error when trying to plot a histogram

Tags: r, histogram

I am trying to plot a histogram. However, even though all the values appear to be numeric or NA, when I try to run hist() it still returns an error. Any help would be appreciated.

```
corruption <- read.csv("Corruption.csv")
corruption[ corruption == "-" ] <- NA
hist(corruption$X2015)
```

I suspect it has something to do with the presence of the '-' character. When I use table(corruption$X2015), this is the output:

```
 - 11 12 15 16 17 18 19 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 44 45 
 0  1  1  2  2  3  4  1  3  3  1  1  6  3  6  7  4  2  5  5  4  4  4  7  5  7  4  1  2  3  5  1 
46 47 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 58 60 61 62 63 65 70 71 74 75 76 77 79  8 81 83 85 86 87 88 89 90 
 2  2  1  1  4  2  3  1  4  3  1  1  3  2  2  1  4  1  1  3  2  1  2  2  3  1  1  1  2  1  1  1 
91 
 1
```

Comment: You probably have this data as a factor; that won't be changed by turning "-" to NA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert `X2015` to numeric which will automatically change non-numerics to `NA`.

```
corruption$X2015 <- as.numeric(as.character(corruption$X2015))
```

You can then use `hist`

```
hist(corruption$X2015)
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! Can you explain why I need to use as.numeric AND as.character instead of just as.numeric? I attempted the latter but it did not work.

Comment: @Wing.Wong273 factors are internally stored as numers. If you directly use `as.numeric`, you get the underlying number. See the output of `as.numeric(factor(c(12, 10)))` vs `as.numeric(as.character(factor(c(12, 10))))`